# is it possible for a machine to not have console session?

Tags: console

At any given time, it is possible for a windows computer to not have a console session?
For example, if after a computer is started and no one ever log-on, would it have a console session?
I thought console session is like KVM and if you have windows logon screen, you would have console sesison by then...

Comment: Does "Server Core" (in Windows Server 2008 or later) count as "a windows computer"?

Comment: @BenVoigt Server Core still has a console session.

Comment: I have no console session running on my Windows machine at the moment. Only time I normally do is if I directly or indirectgly invoke `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @martineau Open `tsadmin.msc` and connect to the machine. The "Sessions" tab will show you a session `Console`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: There's nothing in the question about the Remote Desktop Services Manager. Guess you're a mind reader.

Comment: @martineau `tsadmin` is just a tool to display what's there. The console session is what you see when you plug a monitor into any given Windows computer. It exists on every Windows.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I can't open `tsadmin.msc` because it doesn't exist on my Windows machine. When I look at all the processes running in Task Manager, there's nothing named "console". Same thing using with Process Explorer, so I beg to differ.

Comment: @martineau Differ as much as you like, that won't change anything about the [fact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The console *session* is not a process, so you certainly won't be able to see it in Task Manager or Process Explorer (or any other process viewer).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Obviously not everyone has a "Remote Desktop Services–enabled computer".

Comment: @martineau Like I said before, the console session is what is displayed on the monitor plugged into your computer. Terminal Services just provide *additional* sessions, and the tools allow to show all of them *including* the console session. And now you can go ahead and believe whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/21153/156043) to a similar question. The console session always exists, no matter if a user is logged in or not.