# Is it possible login after end remote desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-control

Is it possible to stay login after I close remote desktop session? I need end session a I needn't logout computer.

I have to need unlock state on computer which was remote control, after I end session.

**Description situation:**
I connect to the computer which works like information panel in our building and I done some stuff, now I disconnect from the panel and the panel is logout and I need ,when I disconnect, it will login automatically after end this session. I can't use a teamviewer.

Comment: a little bit more of a description would be nice, I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: I connect to the computer which works like information panel in our building and I done some stuff, now I disconnect from the panel and the panel is logout and I need ,when I disconnect, it will login automatically after end this session. I can't use a teamviewer.

Comment: Related: [What exactly is the console session in RDP?](http://superuser.com/questions/21145/what-exactly-is-the-console-session-in-rdp)

Comment: Please explain if you really need to automatically make the computer log in to a new session (like you commented above), or do not want to end the current session (which your *"I needn't logout computer"* might suggest). Also, you probably do NOT want to connect to the console session (see my link above) as then everyone would see what you're doing, so: how are you connecting?

Comment: (Also, please use the "edit" link to add that information, and make your question clear, instead of responding in the comments.)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to `disconnect` your session. This way your session is kept logged in but in a locked state.

When you reconnect and unlock your session it is resumed.

To disconnect, close the remote desktop session by pressing the close (X) button or use the commandline tool `tsdiscon`.

If your session is within a corporate environment, the administrator may have disabled disconnection settings (using group policies) to prevent disconnected sessions filling up the systems.

Comment: I have to need unlock state on computer which was remote control, after I end session.

Comment: @YogiBear - That isn't possible.