# Connecting or disconnecting RDP drops VPN?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc

I have a very similar issue to what is described here: [RDP to computer at home](https://superuser.com/questions/952465/rdp-to-computer-at-home-that-is-vpned-to-work-network-drops-vpn-after-rdp-logi)

I have a local server which connects to a client through a VPN.

I am trying to connect to connect to the server though RDP, but as soon as I connect, or disconnect. the connection drops.

Once on RDP I can re-connect just fine, but if I disconnect or loose connection or try logging in locally or from another machine the VPN drops as well.

VNC works fine, but it is limited to the local resolution which is limited to 800x600 on the server which is difficult to work with. RDP allows the remote session to be at any resolution or in my case the resolution of the connecting machine.

Once RDP is connected then VNC works at the RDP resolution and no disconnects happen as long as the RDP session remains running.

In summary, I am looking to connect to a server locally and securely without affecting the servers VPN connection, but also connect at a resolution beyond what the server can do locally.

The VPN client is by GlobalProtect (which seems much less stable than the Cisco client used before.) and I RDP to the console session if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a security feature of GlobalProtect. Whenever someone connects through RDP it requires the user to re-authenticate to prevent VPN access to someone who has gained RDP access to the machine, but who isnt authorized to use the VPN.

Unfortunately there does not appear to be an option to disable this "feature"

Source: 
https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/documentation/70/pan-os/newfeaturesguide/globalprotect-features/rdp-connection-to-a-remote-client